# package/class imports in jasperreport fails after upgrade 6.3.0 -> 6.3.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports, upgrade

I have an application that compiles a lot of reports at build time and fills them at user requests during run time.
I use the library version of jasperreports as dependency through Maven. I just increased the version number to 6.3.1. I was prepared for API changes and different behavior with the new version. However there is one thing I just can't seem to work out...

I use a utility package in some "text field"-elements in report designs that use (static) methods for stuff like formatting or validation. The package is in the same project and after compiling in the same .jar-file as the reports. Example:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[TemplateUtils.formatIban($P{iban})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The package is also imported in the report:

```
<import value="de.company.app.utils.*"/>
```

The problem is that this package and other classes in my own packages are no longer recognized when trying to compile reports:

> de.company.app.utils cannot be resolved

These packages are definitely on classpath of the project. Also, external libraries referenced as Maven dependencies (like Apache commons) are recognized without trouble and reports using them compile as usual. Only my own packages in the project are affected.

Even when trying to compile directly through the Eclipse plugin or a fresh installation of Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.3, compiling fails with the same error.
I've gone through the changelog and didn't find anything relating to this.

Comment: Do you have an ecj jar in your application?  What's the version?

Comment: Yes, it comes as dependency for jasperreports. Version is 4.3.1 for org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj for both 6.3.0 and 6.3.1 of jasperreports library.

Comment: The problem might be related to the change at https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/commit/3a5c3970ddef96b2abdabd31faa5cd4fd238792a
Could you try if using a recent ecj (4.6.0 or newer) in your project's pom.xml makes any difference?  If not, can you describe your setup (e.g. are the de.company.app.utils classes in a jar or folder, Java version, OS)?

Comment: I've already tried explicitly declaring the ECJ dependency while at the same time excluding it from jaserreports but unfortunately it didn't work. I will update the question with more information.